# PHP: Measure size in kilobytes of a object/array?

Tags: php, caching, size, memcached, storage

- What's an appropriate way of measure
  a PHP objects actual size in
  bytes/kilobytes?

Reason for asking:
I am utilizing memcached for cache storage in my web application that will be used by non-technical customers. However, since memcached has a [maximum size of 1mb](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_data_size_you_can_store?_(1_megabyte))  , it would be great to have a function set up from the beginning that I can be used to measure size of selected objects/arrays/datasets, to prevent them from growing to big.

Note that I am only planning on using this as a alert/diagnostic tool to keep track of the cache performance and storage possibilities over time. I assume that calculating speed on each memcached set/add call would slow down things a bit.

I am also aware of storing big datasets in memcached takes away the whole idea of storing things in the RAM, and that is exactly why I need to know in beforehand to prevent customers building up to big datasets.

Thanks a lot

Comment: See below the official manual page. http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php And you will find "Parameters > var" section. > The variable to store. Strings and integers are stored as is, other
> types are stored serialized.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, since Memcached doesn't store raw objects (it actually stores the serialiezd version), you can do this:

```
$serializedFoo = serialize($foo);
if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
    $size = mb_strlen($serializedFoo, '8bit');
} else {
    $size = strlen($serializedFoo);
}
```

Comment: Hi! That's just what I was about to ask. How does it handle UTF8 and multiple byte characters?

Comment: Well, it all depends.  If you have mb_string function overloading on, then you have issues.  If not, `strlen` will return the byte length (which is what you want in the first place).  If you have `mbstring.func_overload` on, you can use `mb_strlen(serialize($foo), '8bit');` in place of strlen.  But note, mb_string must be installed to use it.  I'll edit in a more robust version...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ircmaxell! Great stuff

Comment: @ircmaxell on line 5 of the script you have one too many paranthesis. (can't edit, because SO says edit must have at least 6 characters).

Answer (score -2):

Another easy way pute content of array to file and then check file size.

```
$str = print_r($array, true);
file_put_contents('data.txt', $str);
$size = filesize('data.txt');
```

Comment: What? Never do that!

Comment: It would be a challenge to find a method that is more inefficient than this one..

Comment: Don't you dare doing this