# Handling splitting and joining of objects in key-value storage?

Tags: php, memcached, split, sharding

After [getting some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072452/php-measure-size-in-kilobytes-of-a-object-array) on how to measure fysical/actual size of memcached objects to prevent them from growing too large, I have thought about the next step - implementing a sharding/splitting function that transparently splits large objects into smaller pieces upon storage and glues them together as one big object when requesting them. Basically it should do  everything behind the scenes automatically that needs to be done to keep memcached happy.

What's an appropriate way to handle splitting of array, objects or whatever kind of objects?

I am using PHP in my webapp, but for this case, I would be quite happy with a general approach  with some psuedo-code to point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Holy crap, if you're seriously storing *PHP serialized objects* that are a meg in size, I think you have more problems than having to split them to fit into memcached!

Comment: No, they will not be a megabyte in size, but maybe 50kb or 100kb each in the extreme cases, so if I would have two or three of those I would need to handle the splitting and joining smoothly...

Comment: I hope you understand that the 1mb limit is *per key*, not total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the other question, `serialize` is used to measure the stored length of the object.  If you're hitting the default one meg limit on object size, and you need to split things up, you can simply use `serialize`, [split the resulting string into appropriate chunks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php), and then store the chunks.  Later you can `join` them back together again and `unserialize` the result.

That being said... seriously, if your object, serialized, is a meg in size, you might want to reconsider how you're storing things.  PHP's serialize can be a bit slow (compared to, say, `json_encode`), and throwing a meg or more of data at it is not likely to be the best or fastest way to do whatever it is you're doing.

If you're implementing memcached and sharding as a performance mechanism, I urge you to stop right now unless you've already used a tool like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to profile your code and have eliminated all other bottlenecks.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help! No worries about the size though. I am certain that we won't come close to any 1mb limits in production thanks to the help we got earlier by measuring the increase of size over time and thereby being able to take countermeasures. However, by utilizing your approach we would be able to keep all datasets that are stored to memcached tidy and in appropriate size.