# What is the max size of a single POST variable in PHP?

Tags: php, configuration

is there a way in PHP to set the max size of a single POST variable (not the whole POST size as we do with `post_max_size`)?

EDIT: I was looking for a way to limit the size of a single POST param, not the whole POST. But it seems that you can't do that in PHP and you have to use `post_max_size` (therefore you set the limit of the whole POST).

Comment: do you mean a general configuration as  post_max_size in php.ini?
Or you just want to validate the size after the submit? As far as I know, the first option does not exist.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: whats the total length of a post global variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276759/php-whats-the-total-length-of-a-post-global-variable)

Comment: This may be helpful for you [PHP: Measure size in kilobytes of a object/array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072452/php-measure-size-in-kilobytes-of-a-object-array)

Comment: @Styphon I am trying to limit the size of a single POST parameter when sending a long string back to the server. As I undertood, `post_max_size` limits the size of the whole POST request (no matter how much parameters you put into it, of course if don't hit `max_input_vars`), but I wanted to know if I can limit the size of a single parameter, ex. `$_POST['this_param_contains_a_long_long_string']`

Comment: How about using the [maxlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength) attribute? UTF-8 uses up to 4 bytes per character, just divide the max size you want by four and that's the maximum number of characters you should allow.

Comment: @Styphon Yeah, that could be a solution, but in my specific case I needed to send back a long JSON string to the server (a JSON which I modify on the client side and add even more data to send back through AJAX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your  **php.ini** file

```
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Change these value in php.ini if you've access to it, otherwise you can try to change them in an **.htaccess** file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
```

This will work only if the AllowOverride settings permit it. Otherwise, you've to ask to your hosting company.

Comment: It seems `post_max_size` is the only way. It's not a file by the way. I was working with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` forms.

Comment: yeah it's the only way, you can't use **ini_set()** to change it, because `post_max_size` is used before your script is started, so the only way to set it, is editing .htaccess or php.ini files